# Change color of <a> item with querySelectorAll and specific innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I need to change a menu dropdown item only if it is "Saldos".

I'm using a array to select all the parent elements and passing it to a function, which selects the inside  and checks if it contains the text.

However it does not work, even if I put if(1).

```
var menuArrayHeader = document.querySelectorAll(".drawer__nav-item");

menuArrayHeader.forEach(verificarVermelho)

function verificarVermelho(menuItemParent){
    var menuItem =menuItemParent.querySelector(".drawer__nav-link");
    console.log(menuItem.innerHTML);

    if(menuItem.innerHTML.includes("Saldos")){
        menuItem.style = "color: red !important;";
    }
}
```

The website I'm testing the code on is https://www.karitaideale.com.br/pages/karita

[image: Example]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have u tried menuItem.style .color= "red"

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the issue. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to make it runnable here.

Comment: Your code works perfectly, it could  be optimized of course. The only issue is that you're targeting the wrong parent and link: you're making red the Saldos in the *drawer* navigation, not the one in the *top bar* navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `.innerText` instead of `innerHTML` to find the actual text inside that container.

```
menuArrayHeader.forEach(verificarVermelho)

function verificarVermelho(menuItemParent){
    var menuItem = menuItemParent.querySelector( ".drawer__nav-link" );
    console.log( menuItem.innerText );

    if( menuItem.innerText === "Saldos" ) ) {
        $( menuItem ).attr( 'style', 'color: red !important;' );
    }
}
```

**Also, keep in mind that you need to set the color property on the `a` element child inside the `li` to override the already set property `color: #000` on that `a` element.**

Screenshots from the "Karita" website:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please include code as text, not as pictures of text.

Comment: OP is probably using includes because the HTML contains spaces, that is not the problem.

Comment: That's not any code suggestion. That's screenshots from the site he's trying to manipulate. But yea, I'll describe that it is next time.

Answer (score 0):

`HTMLELement.style` is read-only, you must set its sub properties. In your case,

```
menuItem.style.color = "red";
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style#Setting_styles

> Styles should not be set by assigning a string directly to the style property (as in `elt.style = "color: blue;"`), since it is considered read-only, as the style attribute returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object which is also read-only. Instead, styles can be set by assigning values to the properties of style

Comment: It works perfectly on the chrome dev tools, but if I put the script in the main html file it does not work.

Even if I use a setTimeout or window.onload the code runs, but the property isnt changed